# Binding information in WCF service to consume web service asmx (EWS) which has OAuth2.0 authentication mechanism

Tags: oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices, wcf-binding

I am looking for binding information (for WCF service) to consume EWS asmx (exchange web service) with authentication OAuth 2.0.

I am having WCF service which calls EWS asmx web service to do outlook exchange operation. This set up works fine with Outlook Exchange OnPrem set up.
Now I want to migrate this for exchange online. Authentication mechanism is by using OAuth 2.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

I am able to generate token using my AppId & TenantID and call EWS without any issues from my console application. Same way I am able to generate token in my WCF service as well which calls EWS asmx however, strugging with specifying binding information in the web.config file.

I have tried all the possible options here but getting different exceptions all the time like
-"The http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'ntlm'. The authentication header received from server was 'Basic Realm=""'.

- "The http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from server was 'Basic Realm=""'.

Just one example of binding I tried

```
<binding name="XXXX" ....useDefaultProxy="true">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialsType="Windows" proxyCredentialsType="Basic" realm="*" />
        <message clientCredentialsType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

Can anyone suggest what should be the binding information in wcf service to call asmx which has OAuth2.0 authentication mechanism ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most likely that you did not enable authentication, you can find your service in iis, and then open it in Authentication.[image]

You need to turn off Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication.

[image]

Comment: service my WCF service is consuming is microsoft ews service "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx". Please refer the link I have added for authentication of ews.